# Convert a query to geojson

Tags: python-3.x, django, geojson, geodjango

I need help with this error that I am being presented with and it is the following. I have a database that when I perform the query has a list of points throughout the city, these points are in latitude and longitude format separately, now I need to pass them to geodjango and I need to serialize the data to convert it into geojson but I can't find the way to find the solution, I have the data like this from the database:

```
{'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'name': 'Centro Puerto Lopez', 'direction': 'Calle 5 # 7-28', 'latitude': '4.08467', 'longitude': '-72.9558', 'city': 'Puerto Lopez', 'department': 'Meta', 'pk': '97'}, 'geometry': None}, {'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'name': 'Bachue Acacias', 'direction': 'Carrera 35 # 14-23', 'latitude': '3.98454', 'longitude': '-73.777', 'city': 'Acacias', 'department': 'Meta', 'pk': '98'}, 'geometry': None}, {'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'name': 'Ciudad Porfia', 'direction': 'Carrera 43 # 67-04 Sur', 'latitude': '4.07094', 'longitude': '-73.6695', 'city': 'Villavicencio', 'department': 'Meta', 'pk': '99'}, 'geometry': None}, {'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'name': 'Ciudad Milenio', 'direction': 'Calle 53 S # 33 - 02', 'latitude': '4.08341', 'longitude': '-73.6645', 'city': 'Villavicencio', 'department': 'Meta', 'pk': '100'}, 'geometry': None}]}
```

The data is displayed, I am trying to serialize it like this:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView, TemplateView
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.core.serializers import serialize
import json

from apps.pdv.models import Pdv, Market
from apps.pdv.forms import PdvForm

# Create your views here.

# Clase para listar los pdv
class baseView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "base/maps_base.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        market =  Pdv.objects.all()
        # for mark in market:
        #     print(mark)
        context["markers"] = json.loads(serialize("geojson", Market.objects.all()))
        context["markers_"] = json.loads(serialize("geojson", Pdv.objects.all()))
        # print(context["markers"])
        print(context["markers_"])
        return context
```

but the data that the serialization returns is like this, clearly it is not understanding how to pass latitude and longitude to it so that it can be converted into a point.

```
{'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'name': 'Ciudad Porfia', 'direction': 'Carrera 43 # 67-04 Sur', 'latitude': '4.07094', 'longitude': '-73.6695', 'city': 'Villavicencio', 'department': 'Meta', 'pk': '99'}, 'geometry': None}, {'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'name': 'Ciudad Milenio', 'direction': 'Calle 53 S # 33 - 02', 'latitude': '4.08341', 'longitude': '-73.6645', 'city': 'Villavicencio', 'department': 'Meta', 'pk': '100'}, 'geometry': None}]}
```

I forgot to comment on a code snippet of the model

```
class Pdv(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, verbose_name="Nombre del PDV")
    direction = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Dirección")
    latitude = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Latitud")
    longitude = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Longitud")
    # latitude = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Latitud")
    # longitude = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Longitud")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Ciudad')
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Departamento')

     # We create the str that returns us when the class is called
    def __str__(self):
        # self.datos = [self.name, self.direction, self.latitude, self.longitude, self.city, self.department]
        return self.name

    # Funcion para convertir todos los campos a json y ser devueltos a la vista
    def toJson(self):
        item = model_to_dict(self)
        return item

    # They are changes that I can make to impact the db and registry of the django admin
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Pdv"
        verbose_name_plural = "Pdvs"
        db_table = "pdv"
```

They ask me that the user can enter the coordinates by means of an input in float. I can't put a point because it turns me into a map and they don't want it that way, they have to receive them as text.

How else can you guide me in this way to guide me more?

I hope you can better guide me to solve my error, I thank you from the bottom of my heart for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this (if you didn't already): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/serializers/

It's not really that the serializer doesn't understand your data, your data is simply not formatted in an ideal way, why don't you already output it with a geometry object that contains the proper `coordinates: [lat, lng]`?

Your GeoJSON objects would ideally look something like this:

```json
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Centro Puerto Lopez",
        "direction": "Calle 5 # 7-28",
        "latitude": "4.08467",
        "longitude": "-72.9558",
        "city": "Puerto Lopez",
        "department": "Meta",
        "pk": "97"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-72.9558, 4.08467]
    }
}
```

So you could try something like this (note the new [import](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geos/)!):

```py
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

class Pdv(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, verbose_name="Nombre del PDV")
    direction = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Dirección")
    latitude = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Latitud")
    longitude = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Longitud")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Ciudad')
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Departamento')

    location = Point(longitude, latitude)
```

and then you might be able to do something like this later on when serializing:

```
context["markers_"] = json.loads(serialize("geojson", Pdv.objects.all(), geometry_field='location'))
```

don't know if that would work though...

Comment: Can you guide me how should I pass the coordinates?

Comment: Have a look at the example output on the link above: `      'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [-87.650175, 41.850385]
      },`

Comment: What is "it" and what does the method `model_to_dict` look like?

Comment: Where would I put that sentence if serialize only accepts two parameters, within serialize it does not allow the concatenation to be created, a little clearer help, please.

Comment: updated my answer above, not sure if it helps, but try it out

Comment: class Pdv(models.Model):
  File "/home/cchavita/Documentos/date/apps/pdv/models.py", line 17, in Pdv
    location = Point(longitude, latitude) 
  File "/home/cchavita/Documentos/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/point.py", line 35, in __init__
    raise TypeError("Invalid parameters given for Point initialization.")
TypeError: Invalid parameters given for Point initialization.

Comment: Sounds like either the values are null or empty or the wrong type (e.g. strings instead of floats or something alike)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your models.py snippet as well ?

The reason your serialize is not returning proper geojson is because is expects a GeometryField:

Example:

[image]

[image]

Solution 1:

**If you can alter the models.py**

So, in order for serialize to work you need to create a geometry field ( In your case PointField should be apt).
eg :

In models.py, add

```
point = models.PointField(srid=4326, null=True,blank=True)
```